# Convert .BMP to .PNG with PHP

Tags: php, image, png, bmp

I needed to be able to convert different image formats to the .PNG format. With the help of some others, I was able to make that happen. The only issue is, I also need to be able to convert .BMP files to .PNG without the use of ImageMagick.

**Here is the code I used for the conversion of other files:**

```
<?php
 $filename = "myfolder/test.jpg";
 $jpg = @imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
 if ($jpg)
 {
   header("Content-type: image/png");
   imagepng($jpg);
   imagedestroy($jpg);
   exit;
 }
?>
```

If anyone knows how I would go about converting this, please let me know. All help is welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a new opensource project on Github that allows reading and saving of BMP files (and other file formats) in PHP.

The project is called [PHP Image Magician](http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com).

Comment: The site is broken, it does not load the library page. But I can find the project in github https://github.com/Oberto/php-image-magician. But the read me also does not help.

Comment: @Mani, Yeah, sorry about that. It's down while I'm changing hosts so should be up in the next couple of days. I've added a link to github - I'll try add some documentation on Github, too.

Answer (score 3):

There is not built in functionlaity for standard BMP's in GD. However, if you look at the documentation page for [`imagecreatefromwbmp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromwbmp.php) there are some solutions posted by others you can try. The deal with reading the image data manually and constructing a GD image resource from it which could then be saved as whatever format.

Comment: There are more solutions at the [`imagecreate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php) page.